# cant find my way to register my website on developers.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the `Facebook graph API`. What I want to do is that if I have email address of a person I want to see if he have a Facebook account with that ID. so I Googled a little and found that i can use this.

```
graph.facebook.com\search?q=abc@xyz.com&type=user
```

where all I have to provide is email ID (In this case it is `abc@xyz.com`) so it I will get some output from Facebook databse for the user ID and I might view his profile. The problem is that I cant figure out how to use this URL to start working. I have created an App on https://developers.facebook.com/apps

and got my **App ID/API Key** and **App Secret** but I think I need to register a URL their so that I can access the Facebook Database. But I cant find where and How. I didnt found any good documantation or so to guide me around. Can anyone be gracious enpough to let me know what to do ?
PS
I use This code to check for everything is alright :

```
<?php
require_once("src/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'api key';
$config[‘secret’] = 'secret';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config); 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo "user = ".$user;
?>
```

and it always returns `user = 0`

Comment: Edit your app settings and add the site url in "Website with Facebook Login"

Comment: Did that already but does not work. I also edited the question have a look at it.

Comment: Not 100%, but I think the graph code you've got only works if the user has accepted your app.  If not then it won't return details.

Comment: @ChrisHarland I don't thinks it works that way because I checked with many email ID's and it gave me results as expected without restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUser` will always return 0 if there is no authorization, that is the point of the function; return an authorized user for the application.

If you are looking for Graph API calls not requiring a valid user then you don't need to use that function. The PHP SDK will use the application token to make calls when no user access token is present.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L407